# Schedule batch class on hourly basis

Tags: batch, schedulebatch

How can we schedule batch class on hourly basis? I wrote code getting error

```
global class scheduledcontainSupportCode implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
      containSupportCodeBatchClass scb = new containSupportCodeBatchClass ();

      String sch = '0 0 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 * * ?';
      system.schedule('containSupportCodeBatch', sch, scb); 
    }
}
```

Error when I try to save :

> Compile Error: You must select an Apex class that implements the Schedulable interface. at

Please help me how can we solve this issue.

Comment: Does `containSupportCodeBatchClass` implement `Schedulable`?

Comment: FYI if you use the schedule `String sch = '0 0 * * * ?'` it will do the same thing as yours